# how to send submit button value to php file by post method

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I am trying to send input type submit button value to codeigniter function through form submit, my input type submit buttons value is generating through the loop

```
<form id="formOne" action="<?php echo base_url(). "one_contr/newFunc"; ?>">

     <?php 

     $total = 20;         

     for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){

     echo "<input type='Submit' name'button' value='$i' />";

     }

     ?>   

</form>
```

so now it's generating buttons upto 19, how do i get which button was clicked in codeigniter function. I tried `$this->input->post('button');` but nothing happend

Comment: Why do you need this? You should use `post` or `get` on a route, not multiple posts... This is a good practice so that you can have a a clean code (in my opinion) thus it`s a matter of values passed to the route/contoller method

Comment: I need to do it this way, I have reason for it please help

Comment: Add a hidden input then..

Comment: so you mean I have to add one more echo, if yes then how it will get attached with the button

Comment: can you please write it for me exactly where it should be

Comment: But still...why do you have multiple buttons (the for)?

Comment: I am trying to make pagination in my way, just for practice I want to do it in new way to explore more, that's it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105444/discussion-between-ka-lin-and-mohsin).

Comment: `name'button'` != `name='button'`. You missed the `=` symbol in your code.

Comment: why it is showing the value up in the url ?

Comment: @mohsin You need to add `method="post"` on your `<form>` tag

Answer (score 0):

View

```
  <form id="formOne" action="<?php echo base_url(). "one_contr/newFunc"; ?>">

         <?php 

         $total = 20;         

         for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++){

         echo "<input type='Submit' name='button[]' value='$i' />";

         }

         ?>   

    </form>
```

Controller

```
$button = $this->input->post('button') // $button = array[]
```

*However i don't recommend :(

Comment: = missing, name='button'

Answer (score 0):

```
#view code#
<form id="formOne" action="<?php echo base_url(). "one_contr/newFunc"; ?>">
<?php 
$total = 20 ;
for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++)
echo "<input type='Submit' name='button' value='{$i}'>";
?>
##Controller Code##
/*echo "<pre>";
 *print_r($_REQUEST);//Form data
 */
$data = $this->input->post('button');
```